# Selenium + Java. Как передать переменную внутри xPath?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Здравствуйте, дорогие друзья!

Во время написания автотестов возникла потребность передачи не статического xPath, а более-менее динамического. Объясню на примере:

Есть xPath:

```
"//select[@id = '1']/option[@text() = 'Текст']"
```

Есть переменные:

```
String num = "1";
String text = "Текст";
```

Необходимо передать эти переменные внутри xPath:

```
"//select[@id = num]/option[@text() = text]"
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо константы формируйте строку xPath каждый раз:

```
String xpath = "//select[@id = '" + num + "']/option[@text() = '" + text + "']";
```

или так

```
new StringBuilder("//select[@id = '")
    .append(num)
    .append("']/option[@text() = '")
    .append(text)
    .append("']").toString();
```

или используя `String#format()`:

```
String.format("//select[@id = '%s']/option[@text() = '%s']", num, text);
```

Вариантов масса.